# The range slider disappears after removing a chart from the dashboard

Tags: angular, lightningchart

I have a component with methods:

```
ngOnInit(): void { 

this.chartEventsService.onTrackAdded$$
  .pipe(debounceTime(this.DEFAULT_DELAY_MS), untilDestroyed(this))
  .subscribe(({ track }: ITrackAddedEvent) => {
    this.addChart(track);
    this.setRowsHeights();
  });

this.chartEventsService.onTrackRemoved$$
  .pipe(debounceTime(this.DEFAULT_DELAY_MS), untilDestroyed(this))
  .subscribe(({ trackId }: ITrackRemovedEvent) => this.removeChart(trackId));

this.init();
}

private init(): void {
    timer(this.DEFAULT_DELAY_MS).subscribe(() => {
      this.initDashboard();
      this.initCharts();
      this.synchronizeTimeDepthAxisIntervals();
    ;
    });
  }

 private initDashboard(): void {
    this.dashboard = lightningChart()
      .Dashboard({
        container: this.container.nativeElement,
        numberOfColumns: this.isAppearanceHorizontal ? 1 : this.MAXIMUM_TRACKS_QUANTITY, // =  MAXIMUM_TRACKS_QUANTITY
        numberOfRows: this.isAppearanceHorizontal ? this.MAXIMUM_TRACKS_QUANTITY : 1
      })
      .setSplitterStyle(emptyLine);
    this.setRowsHeights();
  }

 private addChart(track: ITrack, index: number = this.tracks.length - 1): void {
    let chart: ChartXY = this.dashboard.createChartXY({
      columnIndex: this.isAppearanceHorizontal ? 0 : index,
      rowIndex: this.isAppearanceHorizontal ? index : 0,
      defaultAxisX: { opposite: !this.isAppearanceHorizontal },
    });
    chart = this.chartSharedService.setChartBaseStyles(chart, this.isAppearanceHorizontal);

    this.instances.push({ track, rowIndex: index, chart, series: [], customMarker: null });
    this.redrawTimeDepthAxes();
  }

private removeChart(trackId: string): void {
    const index: number = this.instances.findIndex(instance => instance.track.id === trackId);
    this.instances[index].chart.dispose();
    this.instances.splice(index, 1);
    this.setRowsHeights();
    this.redrawTimeDepthAxes();
  }

private setRowsHeights(): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.MAXIMUM_TRACKS_QUANTITY; i++) {
      this.isAppearanceHorizontal
        ? this.dashboard.setRowHeight(i, 0)
        : this.dashboard.setColumnWidth(i, 0);
    }

    const size: number = 100 / this.tracks.length;
    const growIndex: number = this.isAppearanceHorizontal ? 0.08 : 0;
    const mainTrackGrowIndex: number = (growIndex * this.tracks.length) + 1;

    this.tracks.forEach((track: ITrack, index: number): void => {
      const relativeSize: number = index === this.tracks.length - 1 ? size * mainTrackGrowIndex : size;
      this.isAppearanceHorizontal
        ? this.dashboard.setRowHeight(index, relativeSize)
        : this.dashboard.setColumnWidth(index, relativeSize);
    })
  }

  private synchronizeTimeDepthAxisIntervals(): void {
    const axes: Axis[] = this.isAppearanceHorizontal
      ? this.instances.map(instance => instance.chart.getDefaultAxisX())
      : this.instances.map(instance => instance.chart.getDefaultAxisY());
    synchronizeAxisIntervals(...axes)
  }

 private redrawTimeDepthAxes(): void {
    this.instances.forEach(({ chart }: IChartDashboardInstance, index: number) => {
      const isMainAxis: boolean = this.isAppearanceHorizontal ? index === this.tracks.length - 1 : index === 0;
      this.setDefaultStylesToTimeDepthAxis(chart, isMainAxis);
    })
  }
```

When I add a track (chart), my range slider is displayed, but when I remove the last one, the range slider disappears.

When I added charts:

[image]

After removing the track 3:

[image]

What do I need to fix so that the range slider doesn't disappear after removing the last chart?

After removing last chart, the range slider doesn`t disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't show the code that hides the X axes (or "range slider").

I guess you are using `Axis.setVisible(false)` or `Axis.setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Empty)`. To revert those operations (and show the axis), you can use `Axis.setVisible(true)` or `Axis.setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Time)`, etc.